# how to use backdropFilter in js file and not css without error

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the following bunch of code:

```
export const ErrorBlur = {
  width: '95.8%',
  height: '100vh',
  backdropFilter: blur('10px'),
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(124, 146, 153, 0.29)',
};
```

but I get the following error:

> unexpected use of blur

How can I fix the syntax error?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if `blur` is a function, but my guess is that you should set the value of the `backdropFilter` as a string.

```js
export const ErrorBlur = {
  width: '95.8%',
  height: '100vh',
  backdropFilter: 'blur(10px)',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(124, 146, 153, 0.29)',
};
```